# PHP unexpected redirect

Tags: php

I have a php script that I invoke via an ajax call with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  type: "POST",
  url: "getFares.php",
  data: someObjectHere,
  success: function(data) {
    handleSuccess(data);
  },
  dataType: "json"
});
```

Most of the time this request works just fine and the server sends the values that I would expect.

Sometimes however, the server just responds with a 303 SEE OTHER response. Nowhere in my php script is anything that could produce this redirect.

Unfortunately I have not been able to find any kind of pattern when the redirect happens. It appears like it only happens when I load the page, then wait for a bit and then invoke the ajax request, but this might be coincidence.

I know this is not a very helpful description but unfortunately I'm stuck here so I'm hoping that someone by luck knows how to fix it.

Here are a couple of screenshots of the dev tools that should illustrate the problem more clearly:

In this image you can see that I've made a couple of request to the script (getFares.php) and I've highlighted one that worked. You can see the status code is 200 and everything is fine.
[image: Working request]

Here I've highlighted a failed request. The response is 303 See other. As you can see, none of the other values of the request have changed
[image: Failed Request]

The only difference in the requests that I have been able to find is seen here. For requests that return the correct result (status 200), the type is "xhr" and for requests that result in the redirect are of type "x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". I don't know why this happens or where it comes from.
[image: Request overview]

I assume the problem could be related to faulty server/php settings but it's difficult to search for this kind of error.

Comment: Your ajax function seems to be executing as and when you page is loading. Why dont you put it in a function, if you need it on some activity like onclick or onchnage, etc.

Comment: Its actually triggered by a button that i click

Answer (score 0):

It is not ajax issue but the server itself sending response for some reason.

getFares.php page must be checked for some post parameters, if fulfills, sends 200 response otherwise some other response like 303.

You can check getFares.php code to get more idea.

Comment: i thought so too but as i said in the question, nowhere in the php code is a redirect